# SQL Server Transactional Replication and Users and Roles

Tags: sql-server-2012, replication

With SQL Server Transactional Replication, is it possible to also replicate users and roles from the source to the target database?  This is not something I am able to do.

Comment: I don't think so.  Using AD groups may be a better way to authorize users in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, with Transactional Replication you cannot replicate users and roles from source to target.  A list of database objects that can be published using Transactional Replication is listed in [Publish Data and Database Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559.aspx).

You will need to deploy the users and roles from source to target database using a pre or post snapshot script.  For information on pre and post snapshot scripts refer to:

[Execute Scripts Before and After the Snapshot is Applied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152525.aspx)

[Execute Scripts Before and After the Snapshot is Applied (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152549.aspx)

[Configure Snapshot Properties (Replication Transact-SQL Programming)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147379.aspx)